# PHP upload a file to selected subdirectory

Tags: php, upload, directory, subdirectory

I have a form that will upload to the directory it is in, but I need it to upload to subdirectories or subdirectories of subdirectories from a select. But unsure how to use the select info.

My folder structure is 4 layers of folders

```
Produce
Produce/Meat
Produce/Meat/Beef
Produce/Meat/Beef/Portions
Produce/Meat/Beef/Packaged
Produce/Vegtables
Produce/Vegetables/Fresh
Produce/Vegetables/Fresh/Local etc,.
```

This is my form

```
<form id="Upload" action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<br>
        <label for="fileSelect"><strong>There is a 10MB limit Filesize limit.</strong> Allowed file types are pictures, MSWord, MSExcel, PDF, and plain text. Navigate and choose:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="fileSelect"><br><br>
        Upload to:
        <select name="folder"><option value="this" selected>This folder</option><option value="BBB">Meat</option><option value="CCC">Meat/Beef</option><option value="DDD">Meat/Beef/Portions</option><option value="EEE">Meat/Beef/Packaged</option><option value="FFF">Vegetables</option><option value="GGG">Vegetables/Fresh</option><option value="HHH">Vegetables/Fresh/Local</option><option value="III">Vegetables/Fresh/Packaged</option></select>
        <input class="button" type="submit" name="action" value="Upload to Shared Folder"><br><br>
    </form>
```

Then the upload_file.php has this PHP code

```
<?php

if(isset($_FILES["file"]["error"])){
    if($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    } else{
        $allowed = array("jpg" => "image/jpg", "jpeg" => "image/jpeg", "gif" => "image/gif", "png" => "image/png", "doc" => "application/msword", "docx" => "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "xls" => "application/vnd.ms-excel", "xlsx" => "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "pdf" => "application/pdf", "txt" => "text/plain");
        $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $filetype = $_FILES["file"]["type"];
        $filesize = $_FILES["file"]["size"];

        // Verify file extension
        $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(!array_key_exists($ext, $allowed)) die("Error: This file is not an accepted file type.</br></br>");

        // Verify file size - 10MB maximum
        $maxsize = 200000 * 60;
        if($filesize > $maxsize) die("Error: File size is larger than the allowed 10MB limit.</br></br>");

        // Verify MYME type of the file
        if(in_array($filetype, $allowed)){
            // Check whether file exists before uploading it
            if(file_exists("general/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])){
                echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. Go back and choose another file or rename the original.</br></br>";
            } else{
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                echo "The file was uploaded successfully.</br></br>";
            } 
        } 
        else{
            echo "Error: There was a problem uploading the file - please try again."; 
        }
    }
} else{
    echo "Error: Invalid parameters - something is very wrong with this upload.";
}
?>
```

Is there a way I can take the select value and upload to the subdirectory selected?

Comment: use an `isset` with an `if equal to` value, and move the file to the selection chose, or better yet a switch/case http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- unsure how to do that, is that for the select values? I can make the select values the actual folder names. The folder names never change.

Comment: I posted something for you below to have a look at; commenting would have been too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to do this, so here's one way:

Check to see if the POST array is set (for the dropdown select), then inside check to see if it is equal to a value from the options, then move your file inside the chosen folder:

```
if(isset($_POST['folder'])){

    if($_POST['folder'] == 'this'){

    // move_uploaded_file to said folder

    }

    if($_POST['folder'] == 'BBB'){

    // move_uploaded_file to said folder

    }

    // ... do the same for the others below


}
```

you can also set a default upload folder.

---

**Edit:**

Note: Look for my original snippet inside `// My snippet START` --- `// My snippet END`.

```
<?php

if(isset($_FILES["file"]["error"])){
    if($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    } else{
        $allowed = array("jpg" => "image/jpg", "jpeg" => "image/jpeg", "gif" => "image/gif", "png" => "image/png", "doc" => "application/msword", "docx" => "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "xls" => "application/vnd.ms-excel", "xlsx" => "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "pdf" => "application/pdf", "txt" => "text/plain");
        $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $filetype = $_FILES["file"]["type"];
        $filesize = $_FILES["file"]["size"];

        // Verify file extension
        $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(!array_key_exists($ext, $allowed)) die("Error: This file is not an accepted file type.</br></br>");

        // Verify file size - 10MB maximum
        $maxsize = 200000 * 60;
        if($filesize > $maxsize) die("Error: File size is larger than the allowed 10MB limit.</br></br>");

        // Verify MYME type of the file
        if(in_array($filetype, $allowed)){
            // Check whether file exists before uploading it
            if(file_exists("general/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])){
                echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. Go back and choose another file or rename the original.</br></br>";
            } else{

// My snippet START 
    if(isset($_POST['folder'])){

        if($_POST['folder'] == 'this'){

        // move_uploaded_file to said folder

        $uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/Produce/';
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
                    echo "The file was uploaded successfully.</br></br>";

        }

        if($_POST['folder'] == 'BBB'){

        // move_uploaded_file to said folder

        $uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/Produce/Meat/';
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
                    echo "The file was uploaded successfully.</br></br>";

        }

        // ... do the same for the others below


    }

// My snippet END

            }
        }
        else{
            echo "Error: There was a problem uploading the file - please try again."; 
        }
    }
} else{
    echo "Error: Invalid parameters - something is very wrong with this upload.";
}
?>
```

Comment: I can do this, but no idea where to put that in my code above or what to use where you have '// move upload file to said folder' PHP is new to me.

Comment: @Kilisi You would put that entire snippet inside the `else{
                move_uploaded_file....}` where you have `move_uploaded_file`, you would basically copy that method and just change the upload folders accordingly.

Comment: @Kilisi reload my answer and look under **Edit:**. You can keep going with the other folders and just follow that method I did. I used `/var/www/uploads/Produce/` but you will need to change those to match your server's system paths.

Comment: Looks logical, I'll try it out, should be enough to get me in action anyway, cheers.

Comment: @Kilisi *Cheers*

Comment: What is the /var/www ? Is that the site URL? eg,. /https:mysite.com/public_html/Produce/.... in my cpanel editor it's /home/mysite/public_html/Produce

Comment: @Kilisi that was just an example. You will need to use what your cpanel shows you as to what the system path is just as you posted in comments. Make sure that it ends with a trailing slash though, as shown in my answer.